# Independence vs. conditional mean independence

Tags: probability, independence

Independence, i. e. cov(g(e),f(x))=0, can be considered as a stronger assumption than conditional mean independence, i. e. cov(e,f(x))=0.
Does independence, i. e. E{f(x)g(e)}=E{f(x)}E{g(e)} imply conditional mean independence, i. e. resp. E{eIx}=0 ? If yes, how can it be shown?

Comment: Independence is *not* a property that can be generally expressed in terms of covariance.  This raises questions concerning what you mean by "cov": could you please explain?

Comment: For independence I have the definition: e and x are independent, i. e. when for any function g(e) and f(x) the following equation holds E{f(x)g(e)}=E{f(x)}E{g(e)}. Now if I calculate the covariance of g(e) and f(x) I get cov(g(e),f(x))=E{f(x)g(e)}-E{f(x)}E{g(e)} which should be 0 because of E{f(x)g(e)}=E{f(x)}E{g(e)}.
For conditional mean independence (E{eIx}=0) I get cov(e,f(x))=0 using the law of iterated expectations.
So cov(e,f(x)) is a special case of cov(g(e),f(x)) with g(e)=e (identity function).
Now I would like to know how I can derive E{eIx}=0 from E{f(x)g(e)}=E{f(x)}E{g(e)}.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation.  Your question would become more intelligible if you were to explain what your terms $e,x,f,$ and $g$ refer to and to supply suitable quantifiers (specifically, for *all* $f$ and $g$).

Comment: e is supposed to represent the error term of a regression and x is supposed to be a regressor out of the set of regressors.
for example for f(x) one could imagine the log of the earnings, i. e. f(x)=ln(x) and for the error term one could for example imagine g(e)=exp(e)
hopefully this is going to help
i thank you very much for your effort and your patience.
The question deals actually with the causal interpretation of a regression model.
For this E{eIx}=0 is needed. Now I learned that independence is enough to interpret the relationship causally. Therefore I want to figure out the relation

Comment: Thank you, Peter.  If you can, please include those remarks in your post itself--many readers will not read through the comments and might misunderstand the question.